# (un)-Indenting text over a region

Tags: org-mode, indentation

This in org mode. How do I get from

- 1 to 2
- 2 to 3

in as few keystrokes as possible? And, if possible, in reverse. I was hoping selecting Food's subtree and `M-^` would do the job but what it does instead is delete subsequent lines.

## 1

```
* Food
    This is the body,
    which says something about the topic of food.

** Delicious Food
    This is the body of the second-level header.

** Distasteful Food
    This could have
    a body too, with
    several lines.

*** Dormitory Food

* Shelter
    Another first-level topic with its header line.
```

## 2

```
* Food
This is the body,
which says something about the topic of food.

** Delicious Food
This is the body of the second-level header.

** Distasteful Food
This could have
a body too, with
several lines.

*** Dormitory Food

* Shelter
Another first-level topic with its header line.
```

## 3

```
* Food
  This is the body,
  which says something about the topic of food.

** Delicious Food
   This is the body of the second-level header.

** Distasteful Food
   This could have
   a body too, with
   several lines.

*** Dormitory Food

* Shelter
  Another first-level topic with its header line.
```

[image: Key bindings]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### From 1, 3 to 2

- Select all text: <kbd>C-x h</kbd>
- Remove indentation: <kbd>M-x</kbd> <kbd>close-rectangle</kbd> <kbd>RET</kbd>

(Although kind of a hacky use of `close-rectangle`.)

### From 1, 2 to 3

- Select all text: <kbd>C-x h</kbd>
- `indent-region`: <kbd>C-M-\</kbd>

### From 3 to 1

With point at start of buffer:

<kbd>M-x</kbd> <kbd>replace-regexp</kbd> <kbd>RET</kbd>
`^ +` <kbd>RET</kbd> `<4 spaces>` <kbd>RET</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

`C-x h C-M-\` goes directly from 1 to 3

The first part (`C-x h`) runs the command `mark-whole-buffer`, the second (`C-M-\`) runs `indent-region`.

You can go from 1 or 3 to 2 with `C-M-% ^ + RET RET`, that runs the command `query-replace-regexp` to replace any sequence of whitespaces at the beginning of line with nothing.

I don't know how to easily revert the change.